# Overloading <= operator but program ends with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the <= operator but the program has an error

> Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)

op.h

```
bool operator<=(const Date& d1, const Date& d2)
{
    return d1 <= d2;
}
```

main.cpp

```
cout << "Checking <=" << endl;
assert(Date(1,1,2000) <= Date(2,1,2000));
assert(!(Date(2,1,2000) <= Date(1,1,2000)));
assert(Date(2,1,2000) <= Date(1,2,2000));
assert(Date(2,2,2000) <= Date(1,1,2001));
cout << "Checking <= Complete!" << endl;
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Inifinte recursion causes stack overflow Your `operator<=(const Date& d1, const Date& d2)` calls `operator<=(const Date& d1, const Date& d2)` in its body.

Comment: You need to actually put the condition under which one `Date` is smaller/equal than another into your operator overload. The compiler doesn't magically know what these are and as explained by others, the way you are writing it right now just leads to infinite recursion.

Comment: *I am trying to overload the <= operator* -- Why specifically that operator?  In C++, the two operators that are almost defacto overloaded are `==` and `<`.  All of the other relational operators `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `!=`, can be derived from `==` and `<`.  So my advice is to overload `<` and `==`, and then you practically get all the other operators "for free".

Comment: To be more exact, if you have `a < b`, then `a >= b` is simply `!(a < b)`.  Write the function for `<`, and then the function for `>=` is simply `return !(a < b);`.  Similarly, `a <= b` (which you are trying to implement), is `return !(b < a);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you call the

```
bool operator<=(const Date& d1, const Date& d2)
```

indefinitely, wich goes out the stack eventually, because it is a recursion call.
Try to compare directly the content of both your objects passed as parameters.

Comment: @uneven_mark yes in deed, I'm an idiot. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Could you give me an example please? Im still trying to get my head around operator overloading.

Comment: @Leon185 Could you give me the content of your class ? (Date)